# Count children with the relation on the same model in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

I have `folders` table with `folder_id` column. I have to list folders (where `folder_id` is `null` or whatever parent ID) with their children count, so I cant get `folders_count` attribute. I use `withCount` for this purpose, but got loop and browser's default 500 error screen. For now, I solved problem using this:

```php
$builder->addSelect(
    DB::raw('(select count(*) from `folders` `f` where `folders`.`id` = `f`.`folder_id`) as `folders_count`')
);
```

But I want to know if there's a better way to do it without raw select, just using pure Eloquent.

Comment: I need to see the tried eloquent version of this query.

Comment: @dbf, I just added it to global scope:

```public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->addSelect(
            DB::raw('(select count(*) from `folders` `f` where `folders`.`id` = `f`.`folder_id`) as `folders_count`')
        );
    }
```

Comment: No I meant the version you tried with `withCount`. Also, how are the relationships in the `Folder` model called.

Comment: @dbf, ```protected $withCount = ['folders', 'files'];```

Comment: @dbf, how are the relationships in the `Folder` model called:

```public function folders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(static::class)->latest();
    }```

Comment: To be clear, in your `Folder` model, the relationship method to itself is called `folders()` and returns its children to that particular folder?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok, `Folders::withCount('folders')->get()` should absolutely perfectly work. Have you tried without `->latest()`? Does it execute in Tinker?

Comment: Yes, I tried it withour `->latest()`, but it doesn't work.